# Understanding output of apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt

When I run `apt-get upgrade` here is what it says

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1530 not upgraded .
```

It does not give me confirmation or warning messages.
What does mean?

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` might be of use.

Comment: I use apt-get dist-upgrade. It says E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: Can you post `apt-cache policy | egrep -i -v translat` ?

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get upgrade`  Install newest Versions for only current installed packages, but only when no package must be removed or a new one be installed.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` however install newest Versions too, but it solve changes dependencies for new versions of packages.

See, e.g. https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-guide/ch2.en.html
or the [man page for `apt-get`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)